# How to update a variable from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a python project where I have a large dictionary of values for a repair business. I am trying to write a script to update this file, making it easier for me when I want to change it. How would I do this? I have a file, we'll call it `file1.py`. The only thing in this file is a dictionary called `current_dict`. I want to create `file2.py` so that it's only purpose is to update `current_dict` easily. How could I do this? Sorry if this isn't clear.

Example `file1.py`:

```
current_dict = {'index1': {...}, 'index2': {...}}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample (made up) IO for the data you are working with?

Comment: I have a file, we'll call it `file1.py`. The only thing in this file is a dictionary called `current_dict`. I want to create `file2.py` so that it's only purpose is to update `current_dict` easily. Is this a better explanation?

Comment: An example `file1` would be helpful

Comment: I added one, Pro Q. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to update the dict read by your program from the file, or the actual file itself so that the change persists?

Comment: I would want to change the actual file so that the change persists. Thank you all for your help, I know I haven't presented this well.

Comment: See my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57531417/421195) below.  If the data needs to be updated periodically, you do *NOT* want to hard-code it in your .py Python source file.  You want Python to READ it from some EXTERNAL source - for example, a JSON file.  Or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - your question isn't clear :(

But it sounds like you have a Python source file ("file1.py") which has a hard-coded dictionary like this:

```
mydict =    {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
```

... and you want to text-edit "file1.py" with the dictionary from some other file, "file2.py".

If so, one way is to use a text editing tool like "sed" or "awk".

BUT DON'T DO THAT!!!

A better approach is to *EXTERNALIZE* your dictionary.  Ito a *SEPARATE* file, or a separate database.  Your Python app then simply *READS* the data into a dictionary on-the-fly.

For example:

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
```

Updating the file manually is easy.

Updating the file programmatically (with `json.dump()`) is equally easy.